# How to get kernel messages on serial console on a systemd system?

Tags: linux-kernel, systemd, serial-console

I'm trying to set up an [A20-OLinuXino-LIME2](https://www.olimex.com/wiki/A20-OLinuXino-LIME2) as a headless fileserver with a [Debian 8 image](http://mirror.igorpecovnik.com/Lime2_Debian_1.8_jessie_4.0.4.zip) from [Igor Pečovnik's builds](http://www.igorpecovnik.com/2014/11/18/olimex-lime-debian-sd-image/).

I would like the system to output its kernel messages to the serial console (ttyS0) during the boot process and end up with a login prompt on ttyS0.

By default, the image uses the following kernel commandline:

```
console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rootwait rootfstype=ext4 sunxi_ve_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_g2d_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_no_mali_mem_reserve sunxi_fb_mem_reserve=16 hdmi.audio=EDID:0 disp.screen0_output_mode=1920x1080p60 panic=10 consoleblank=0 enforcing=0 loglevel=1
```

… which of course doesn't output any kernel messages to ttyS0 — I get no output whatsoever between the U-Boot's "`Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.`" and systemd spawning the login prompt.

I figured I just needed to replace `console=tty1` with `console=ttyS0,115200n8`, but then systemd grabs the serial console and squelches the kernel, so I only get the bootloader messages, then systemd's "`[  OK  ] Started foo.`"-style messages, and finally the login prompt.

Is there a way to get both the kernel messages ("`[    0.000000] foo`") and systemd's output on ttyS0?
Or a way to at least mute systemd so I can see the kernel messages if I ever need to debug a boot failure?

---

I should add that the kernel definitely supports logging to ttyS0: When I replace the entire kernel commandline with `console=ttyS0,115200n8`, I get the "`[    0.000000] foo`" messages I want, but the kernel naturally panics because it can't find its rootfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> systemd grabs the serial console and squelches the kernel, so I only get the bootloader messages

Does it? It doesn't. The `loglevel=1` in your kernel command line is responsible for telling kernel to stop logging. Try removing that statement (or explicitly setting it to `loglevel=7`).

To stop *systemd* from logging its own status messages, use `systemd.show_status=no` (ref.: [systemd(1)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#systemd.show_status=)).

---

P. S.: please, guys, stop attributing arbitrary software bugs and misconfigurations to systemd.

Comment: P.S. : it doesn't work : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566928/cant-get-kernel-messages-logged-to-the-serial-console-of-a-systemd-system