# Can't get kernel messages logged to the serial console of a systemd system

Tags: linux-kernel, systemd-journald, serial-console

I would like to log the kernel messages of system to the serial console on ttyS0.

A similar problem was addressed under [How to get kernel messages on serial console on a systemd system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211407/how-to-get-kernel-messages-on-serial-console-on-a-systemd-system) but I still don't get it to work.

I've got `systemd.journald.max_level_console=debug` `console=ttyS0,115200` `loglevel=7` on my kernel command line and `ShowStatus=no` set in */etc/systemd/system.conf*

Nevertheless, while I'll see kernel messages on the console at the beginning of the boot process, after the Journal Service is started I wont get any more kernel messages logged to the console.

If I, as an example, connect a USB mouse to the board, there is nothing logged to the console but journalctl -f shows:

```
Feb 11 10:09:45 a20 kernel: usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ohci-platform
Feb 11 10:09:45 a20 kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c069, bcdDevice=56.01
Feb 11 10:09:45 a20 kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Feb 11 10:09:45 a20 kernel: usb 3-1: Product: USB Laser Mouse
Feb 11 10:09:45 a20 kernel: usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
Feb 11 10:09:45 a20 kernel: input: Logitech USB Laser Mouse as /devices/platform/soc/1c14400.usb/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:046D:C069.0005/input/input6
Feb 11 10:09:45 a20 kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C069.0005: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Laser Mouse] on usb-1c14400.usb-1/input0
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`systemd.log_level=debug systemd.log_target=kmsg loglevel=7 systemd.journald.forward_to_console=1`

`log_target` can also be set directly to `console`

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Systemd_problems

https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/

I think this question might be a duplicate, unsure.